# The given key 'dialogs' was not present in the dictionary while using ContinueDialogAsync

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am using Bot Framework SDK v-4. I have created a couple of dialogs inherited from `ComponentDialog` and overridden the methods: `BeginDialogAsync` and `ContinueDialogAsync`. Below is the implementation of the `IBot`.

```
public class Bot : IBot
{
    private readonly BotAccessors _accessors;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private DialogSet _dialogs = null;
    private string _botName = string.Empty;
    private IConfiguration _configuration = null;
    private UserDetail _userDetail = null;
    private ConversationData _conversationData = null;
    private IStatePropertyAccessor<TurnState> _turnStateAccessor = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the class.
    /// </summary>                        
    public Bot(BotAccessors accessors, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _accessors = accessors ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
        if (loggerFactory == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        }

        _configuration = configuration;
        _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)));
        _turnStateAccessor = accessors.TurnStateAccessor;
        _dialogs.Add(new GreetingDialog(_turnStateAccessor, loggerFactory, configuration));
        _dialogs.Add(new QnADialog(_turnStateAccessor, loggerFactory, configuration));
        _botName = configuration["BotName"];
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Bot>();
        _logger.LogTrace("Bot turn start.");
    }

    public override Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        _turnState = _turnStateAccessor.GetAsync(outerDc.Context).Result;
        outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync();
        return base.BeginDialogAsync(outerDc, options, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<DialogTurnResult> ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        _turnState = _turnStateAccessor.GetAsync(outerDc.Context).Result;

        //some code
        _turnStateAccessor.SetAsync(outerDc.Context, _turnState).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return base.ContinueDialogAsync(outerDc, cancellationToken);
    }

}
```

I call the dialog from the `OnTurnAsync` method of the Bot like this: `await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(GreetingDialog)).ConfigureAwait(false);`. It reaches the `BeginDialogAsync` method of my dialog and then continues to `ContinueDialogAsync`. It works fine, however, while returning (using `base.ContinueDialogAsync(outerDc, cancellationToken);`) from the method, I get some exception which I captured from the Diagnostic tool of the Visual Studio.

[image]

Also, I am sending the exception as an activity message to the client (bot framework emulator) which is shown below.

> Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Exception:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   dialogId at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String
>   dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line
>   84 at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext
>   outerDc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line
>   59 at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String
>   dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line
>   84 at Chatbot.Bot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\GIS\ChatbotNew\Chatbot\Chatbot\Bot.cs:line 120 at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55 at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext
>   turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167

**Update-1**

Based on Drew's answer I removed `outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync();` but I get some error (shown below) while stepping through the `return base.BeginDialogAsync(outerDc, options, cancellationToken);` in `BeginDialogAsync` function.

[image]

Also, while stepping through the `OnTurnAsync` function I get an error while trying to get the `BotState` as shown below.

[image]

`TurnState` implementation:

```
public class TurnState
{
    public int TurnCount { get; set; } = 0;
    public string BotType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ConversationLanguage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    //other properties...
}
```

Similar error while trying to create the `DialogContext` as well.

`ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddBot<Bot>(options =>
   {
       var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("botFileSecret")?.Value;

        // Loads .bot configuration file and adds a singleton that your Bot can access through dependency injection.
        var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(@".\Chatbot.bot", secretKey);
       services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig);

        // Retrieve current endpoint.
        var service = botConfig.Services.Where(s => s.Type == "endpoint" && s.Name == "development").FirstOrDefault();
       if (!(service is EndpointService endpointService))
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot file does not contain a development endpoint.");
       }

       //options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(Configuration[MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppIdKey], Configuration[MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppPasswordKey]);
       options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);


       // Creates a logger for the application
       ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Bot>();

        // Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them.
        options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
       {
           await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong. Exception: " + exception);
       };

       // The Memory Storage used here is for local bot debugging only. When the bot
       // is restarted, everything stored in memory will be gone.
       IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();

       var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);

       options.State.Add(conversationState);

   });

    // Create and register state accesssors.
    // Acessors created here are passed into the IBot-derived class on every turn.
    services.AddSingleton<BotAccessors>(sp =>
    {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BotFrameworkOptions>>().Value;
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("BotFrameworkOptions must be configured prior to setting up the state accessors");
        }

        var conversationState = options.State.OfType<ConversationState>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (conversationState == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ConversationState must be defined and added before adding conversation-scoped state accessors.");
        }

        // Create the custom state accessor.
        // State accessors enable other components to read and write individual properties of state.
        var accessors = new BotAccessors(conversationState)
        {
            TurnStateAccessor = conversationState.CreateProperty<TurnState>(BotAccessors.TurnStateName),
        };

        return accessors;
    });
}
```

Any help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to wrap my head around exactly what you're expecting to happen here:

```cs
public override Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    _turnState = _turnStateAccessor.GetAsync(outerDc.Context).Result;
    outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync();
    return base.BeginDialogAsync(outerDc, options, cancellationToken);
}
```

Specifically, why are you calling `outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync()` here? That is basically tying the dialog stack up in a knot. If you removed that line everything else you show here should work perfectly.

If you update your question with some more details on exactly what you were trying to accomplish by calling that I'll happily update my answer to try and set you on the right path for accomplishing whatever that might be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Without calling `outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync()` the `ContinueDialogAsync` function is not getting executed. I was using this approach in the pre-release version of the SDK v-4 so thought of doing the same. More details in the updated question.

Comment: Just an update, I also looked into a solution mentioned here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1080. I still get the same problem.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what the expectation is here, but I can tell u this is not going to work. The `outerDc` here is the `DialogContext` that your custom `ComponentDialog` was just started on by someone else calling `BeginDialogAsync("yourDialogId", ...)` on. By calling `outerDc.ContinueDialogAsync()` u r essentially telling the `DialogContext` to continue yourself and u r doing so in your own "begin" phase. TL;DR:  u r crossing up lifecycle events. If u have logic that needs to happen in both "begin" and "continue" then u should refactor into a helper method and call it from both.

Comment: The problem I described above is way more than just the `outerDc` and `ContinueDialogAsync`. I get errors while trying to get the `BotState`. I also get error while creating the `DialogContext`. These happen within the `OnTurnAsync` during the conversation update/message event.